# How do I get the MAX row with a GROUP BY in LINQ query?

Tags: .net, linq, linq-to-sql

I am looking for a way in LINQ to match the follow SQL Query.

```
Select max(uid) as uid, Serial_Number from Table Group BY Serial_Number
```

Really looking for some help on this one.  The above query gets the max uid of each Serial Number because of the `Group By` Syntax.

Answer (score 102, accepted):

```
        using (DataContext dc = new DataContext())
        {
            var q = from t in dc.TableTests
                    group t by t.SerialNumber
                        into g
                        select new
                        {
                            SerialNumber = g.Key,
                            uid = (from t2 in g select t2.uid).Max()
                        };
        }
```

Comment: I want to accept both as answers, but I guess I can't so I voted for both of you guys. Thanks a BUNCH!!!

Answer (score 74):

```
var q = from s in db.Serials
        group s by s.Serial_Number into g
        select new {Serial_Number = g.Key, MaxUid = g.Max(s => s.uid) }
```

Comment: I want to accept both as answers, but I guess I can't so I voted for both of you guys.

Thanks a BUNCH!!!

Comment: Also note that the variable for the => lambda expression in the Max function can be anything (s => s.uid, tv => tv.uid, asdf => asdf.uid). Linq will automatically recognize it as selecting over elements of type Serial.

Answer (score 42):

In methods chain form:

```
db.Serials.GroupBy(i => i.Serial_Number).Select(g => new
    {
        Serial_Number = g.Key,
        uid = g.Max(row => row.uid)
    });
```

Answer (score 24):

I've checked DamienG's answer in LinqPad.
Instead of

```
g.Group.Max(s => s.uid)
```

should be

```
g.Max(s => s.uid)
```

Thank you!

Comment: This should probably a comment on DamienG's answer.

Answer (score 14):

The answers are OK if you only require those two fields, but for a more complex object, maybe this approach could be useful:

```
from x in db.Serials 
group x by x.Serial_Number into g 
orderby g.Key 
select g.OrderByDescending(z => z.uid)
.FirstOrDefault()
```

... this will avoid the "select new"

Comment: I like this - do you know if it is as efficient as the other answers?

Comment: You used the query syntax here all the way up to the end, where you switched to method syntax. Did you have to? Is the a full query syntax form for your solution?

Answer (score 6):

This can be done using GroupBy and SelectMany in LINQ lamda expression

```
var groupByMax = list.GroupBy(x=>x.item1).SelectMany(y=>y.Where(z=>z.item2 == y.Max(i=>i.item2)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Building upon the above, I wanted to get the best result in each group into a list of the same type as the original list:

```
    var bests = from x in origRecords
            group x by x.EventDescriptionGenderView into g
            orderby g.Key
            select g.OrderByDescending(z => z.AgeGrade)
            .FirstOrDefault();

    List<MasterRecordResultClaim> records = new 
                  List<MasterRecordResultClaim>();
    foreach (var bestresult in bests)
    {
        records.Add(bestresult);
    }
```

EventDescriptionGenderView is a meld of several fields into a string. This picks the best AgeGrade for each event.