# How would I translate following T-SQL statement To Linq

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework

This is my sql syntax

```
select DepartmentId, max(fromdate) from iwof.DateSnippet group by DepartmentId
```

and this is the result that I get

```
1   2013-09-09 14:53:52.813 
2   2014-02-07 14:37:21.740
3   2014-02-07 14:37:21.737
4   2014-02-07 14:37:21.740
5   2014-02-07 14:37:21.743
6   2014-02-07 14:37:21.743
```

Comment: this should help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7325278/group-by-in-linq

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/157786/how-do-i-get-the-max-row-with-a-group-by-in-linq-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax you use is incorrect. Format closer to this, and it should do the trick

```
var results = from p in iwof.DateSnippet
          group p by p.DepartmentId into g
          select new { DepartmentId = g.Key, MaxFromDate = g.Max(fromdate) };
```