# Upgrading to Entity Framework

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I am trying to recover the id to the last document created by a user within my program. The original SQL work is not my own, but I have been tasked with upgrading to EF. Code snippets below. Just need to know how to change the syntax so it works using EF instead. (Using VB.Net)

```
'query for the max item created by the user
SqlString = "SELECT max(IdDocuments) as MaxId FROM Documents WHERE ModifiedBy='" + Environment.UserName.ToLower + "' ;"
SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(SqlString, SqlConnectionString)
TableNow = New DataTable
SqlDataAdapter.Fill(TableNow)
SqlDataAdapter.SelectCommand.Connection.Close()`
```

What I have tried already:

```
DocNow = (From a In Db.Documents Where a.ModifiedBy = Environment.UserName.ToLower)
```

Connection to DB defined as:

```
'query the database
Dim IdNow As Integer = DocumentId
Dim DocNow As IEnumerable(Of Documents) = (From a In Db.Documents Where a.IdDocuments = IdNow).ToList
```

Here is Current code after help from bwyn (SQL included):

```
'if is new, get the last document for this user
        If IsNew Then

            'query for the max item created by the user
            'SqlString = "SELECT max(IdDocuments) as MaxId FROM Documents WHERE ModifiedBy='" + Environment.UserName.ToLower + "' ;"
            'SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(SqlString, SqlConnectionString)
            'TableNow = New DataTable
            'SqlDataAdapter.Fill(TableNow)
            'SqlDataAdapter.SelectCommand.Connection.Close()


            Dim context As New Context()
            Dim lastId As Integer
            Dim currentUser As String = Environment.UserName.ToLower()
            lastId = context.Documents.Where(Function(doc) doc.ModifiedBy = currentUser).Select(Function(doc) doc.IdDocuments).Max()


            'set to the document id
            DocumentId = lastId

        End If
```

Comment: 1) Since in general SQL is not case sensitive, you shouldn't need to call `ToLower`. 2) Are there any issues with this code?

Comment: No this code works as of now, but i have reformatted most of the code to not use data tables and rows, and instead use ienumerables.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/157786/how-do-i-get-the-max-row-with-a-group-by-in-linq-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will query for the current user's documents, select the ids, and then return the max id:

```
    Dim context As New Context()
    Dim lastId As Integer
    Dim currentUser As String = Environment.UserName.ToLower()
    lastId = context.Documents.Where(Function(doc) doc.ModifiedBy = currentUser).Select(Function(doc) doc.Id).Max()
```

**Edit: My context class**

```
Public Class Context
    Inherits DbContext

    Public Property Documents As DbSet(Of Document)

End Class
```

Comment: I think this will work, but what 'using' should i add?

Comment: Using context As New Context()

Comment: I'm sorry I meant for the import. When I implemented your code it gave me an error on the "Dim context as New Context()" . When I use the intellisense, any of the imports it suggest do not fix the error.

Comment: I used the following import statement: Imports System.Data.Entity. I will post my Context class in my answer.

Comment: Okay this should work. Unfortunately I can't test it for a while as i still have about 170 other errors to fix, but I will come back then and confirm for sure!

Comment: I have no idea how to do any of that but thanks! I'm just a co-op programmer so I'll have my boss look at it tomorrow since he wrote the original code and is the one who is teaching me entity.