# Linq Get the maximum version of items from a list

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have a table in sql Server:

```
CREATE TABLE AD_Users (
    [ImportID]          BIGINT           NOT NULL,
    [LogonID]           NVARCHAR (50)    NOT NULL,
    [EmployeeId]        NVARCHAR (64)    NULL,
    [FirstName]         NVARCHAR (64)    NULL,  
    [LastName]          NVARCHAR (64)    NULL,
 ......
```

There are multiple versions of the data for each loginId, keyed by ImportID.  So to get the latest info for each user I use:

```
SELECT LogonID,ImportID,EmployeeId, FirstName, LastName
   FROM AD_Users adUsers where ImportID =  (select Max(ImportID) from 
    AD_Users  a where a.LogonID = adUsers.LogonId);
```

Now I want to do the same thing using Linq.
EF maps this to a data set of:

```
public partial class ActiveDirectoryUser
{
    public long ImportID { get; set; }
    public string LogonId { get; set; }
    public long EmployeeId{ get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    .......
```

So all I need to do is get the items from this dbset which have the max importId for that logonid.

So far I have:

```
var latests = this.DbSet.GroupBy(g => g.SystemUniqueUserID)
```

but I am at a loss where to go after that.  Is it possible to do what I want in linq or should I just generate the SQL?

Not a duplicate of [How do I get the MAX row with a GROUP BY in LINQ query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/157786/how-do-i-get-the-max-row-with-a-group-by-in-linq-query) as this doesn't get the latest version of each item.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get the MAX row with a GROUP BY in LINQ query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/157786/how-do-i-get-the-max-row-with-a-group-by-in-linq-query)

Comment: have you checked the answer(s) below?

Comment: Love the way I get down voted for it being a duplicate...when it's not :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `GroupBy` `LogonId` and the `OrderByDescending` `ImportID` and select the first one, something like

```
    context.AD_Users.GroupBy(u=>u.LogonId).Select(g=>g.OrderByDescending(gg=>gg.ImportID)
.FirstOrDefault())
```

Please check the syntax, I just woke up

Comment: This seems to be what I am after - though you need FirstOrDefault() instead of First() or you get an exception (telling you to use FirstOrDefault!)

Thanks

Comment: You just need to replace `FirstOrDefault` with `.SelectMany(u => u)`. This will give you the desired result

Answer (score 0):

This is a variation of Tejas answer. But this will give you the already existing objects instead of creating new ones.

```
var latest =  (from x in context.AD_Users
              group x by x.LogonId into g
              select context.AD_Users.Where(u => u.LogonId == g.Key 
                     && u.ImportID == g.Max(uu => uu.ImportID)))
              .SelectMany(u => u);
```

Comment: you are doing extra and unnecessary `Where` conditions

Comment: You are doing `GroupBy` which would segregate for each logonid

Comment: This looks very much like the sort of thing I am after only it returns IQueryable<IQueryable<ActiveDirectoryUser>>  but I only need a simple IQueryable  ?

Comment: @Lobsterpants You're right. Didn't recognize that. I've updated my answer to correct that.

Comment: @AD.Net that is correct. But I don't see how to select the maximum object without the where. Could you post an example?

Comment: @RomanoZumbé, after the grouping by logonid, each collection would have all the records for each logonid, so you need to order by each collection by the importid and pick the first one, which by the way was my answer, lol

Comment: @AD.net that is one possible way to do it. Another one is my answer (which I think is more intuitive to read as it clearly shows what is done). As far as I know, the `Where` is needed in my approach. So you are free to remove your downvote ;-)

Comment: But as I said, you're doing extra where conditions. In a table of reasonable size you'll see the difference in performance.

Comment: Do you expect there to be tens of thousands of users in his AD? Maintainability should also be considered. Not only performance.

Comment: @AD.Net Nevertheless, I do like your solution. More than mine ;-). It should be the accepted answer. I just wanted to justify, that there are always other solutions and that those can have a right of existence, too.

Comment: Thanks @RomanoZumbé - a good answer that helped me understand what was going on.