# Querying last items using linq

Tags: c#, linq

So I have a list that ideally query from database using the entity framework

```
var list = context.Items;
```

And the results to fill would be this

```
var list = new List<Item>{
new Item { id=1, operation="write", date="23.03.2018 08:25:45" },
new Item { id=1, operation="read",  date="23.03.2018 09:40:15" },
new Item { id=1, operation="read",  date="23.03.2018 10:15:17" },
new Item { id=1, operation="read",  date="23.03.2018 11:46:39" }
```

So I want to minify this list by operation and last date.

```
var min = new List<Item>{
new Item { id=1, operation="write", date="23.03.2018 08:25:45" },
new Item { id=1, operation="read",  date="23.03.2018 11:46:39" }
```

but I am getting last write operation and last read item

Comment: Clarify: for every unique ID and Operation-Type you want the last record?

Comment: Why the <sql> tag?

Comment: @TimSchmelter yes. sorry i forgot to add the id in haha

Comment: @Denise: i hope `Date` is not a string actually but a `DateTime`

Answer (score 2):

For every unique ID and Operation-Type you want the last record?

Then `GroupBy` and `OrderByDescending` are needed and an anonymous type:

```
var query = context.Items
    .GroupBy(x => new { x.Id, x.Operation } )
    .Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(x => x.Date).First()); // presuming Date is a DateTime not string
```

If `Date` is actually a string as in your sample you should change it to `DateTime`. You really don't want to parse it always. Store the right type in the database. You will get more safety and performance.

Comment: Looks like a manual `.Max()`... I would suggest something similar to `select new{SerialNumber=g.Key,uid =(from t2 in g select t2.uid).Max()};`

Comment: @bradbury9: why you would suggest that? OP doesn't want max-values for single columns, he wants the last record(full record including all columns) for every id-operation combination. In the [question you have linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/157786/how-do-i-get-the-max-row-with-a-group-by-in-linq-query) OP asked something different(similar to this), but actually wanted something else(max-value instead of max-row).

Comment: A grouping by id & operation with a max(date) would accomplish the 'minify this list' requirement.

Comment: @bradbury9: but you return an anonymous type instead of the `Item`. What if there are more columns, you want to use this subquery for every column? My result is an `IEnumerable<Item>`.

Comment: Indeed, depending on the usage your answer would fit better.

Answer (score 0):

Below LINQ will order items by data then group items by operation and select the first item from each group.

```
var result = list.OrderByDescending(d => d.date)
    .GroupBy(i => new { i.id, i.operation })
    .Select(g => g.FirstOrDefault())
    .ToList();
```

Comment: She wants last for id-operation not only for operation(look at her  comment)

Comment: Updated for id and operation

Comment: Now this works in LINQ-To-Objects but OP is using a database. There this query doesn't guarantee the right order because `GroupBy` comes after `OrderbyDescending`.