# LINQ: List with max values

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-5

i have this query in SQL Server

```
select max(win_votos), win.cdt_id, cdt_nome 
   from tb_ganhadores_win as win
   inner join tb_candidatos_cdt as cdt on cdt.cdt_id = win.cdt_id
   group by win.cdt_id,cdt_nome
```

<--

and i need to create a list 'AspNetMvc' page, like

```
public ActionResult ListWinners(int? id){

LINQ QUERY HERE

return View('that list');

}
```

sorry about my english

can anyone help me please?

Comment: are you using Entity Framework and set it up?

Comment: In my opinion the question is too broad for Stackoverflow. Try to go on line and follow basic tutorial. Then if you have issues, come back and show us the code you've tried.

Comment: i have some things that i forgot to say, in the result of query in sql, i have some itens with same max value like Name 1 - 2.0, Name 2 - 2.0 (can u understand what i trying to say?)

Comment: and this is what i can do:
db.Ganhadores
                .Join(db.Candidatos, ganhadores => ganhadores.cdt_id, candidato => candidato.cdt_id, (ganhadores, candidato) => new { ganhadores, candidato })
                .Where(g => g.ganhadores.vot_id == id)
                .Max(g => g.ganhadores.win_votos);

but with this i cant put '.tolist()'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get the MAX row with a GROUP BY in LINQ query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/157786/how-do-i-get-the-max-row-with-a-group-by-in-linq-query)

Comment: I will reformulate my doubt, I have a mini voting system, where when closing the voting, show me the winner. But there may be a tie and I need to be shown how many and which names are tied, I think now it has become clearer right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var res= (from win in dbContext.tb_ganhadores_wins
          join cdt in dbContext.tb_candidatos_cdts
          on win.cdt_id equals cdt.cdt_id
          select new {win,cdt})
          .GroupBy(x=>new{Id=x.win.cdt_id,Nome=x.cdt.cdt_nome})
          .Select(x=>new
                     {
                       Votos=x.Max(z=>z.win.win_votos),
                       Id=x.Key.Id,
                       Nome=x.Key.Nome
                     })
         .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use entity framework and your model name is like this you can use some think like this:

```
var result =  from win in tb_ganhadores_win
              join cdt in tb_candidatos_cdt on cdt.cdt_id = win.cdt_id
              group win by new { win.cdt_id, cdt_nome } into g
                select new
                {
                    max = g.Max(win_votos),
                    win.cdt_id,
                    cdt_nome
                };
```

and return `result.ToList();`

note :

> "tb_ganhadores_win"

and

> "tb_candidatos_cdt"

is your models.Replace it by what you want

Comment: var result = from win in db.Ganhadores
join cdt in db.Candidatos on win.cdt_id equals cdt.cdt_id
group win by new{ win.cdt_id, cdt.cdt_nome} into g
        select new
         {
                 max = g.Max(win.win_votos),
                  win.cdt_id,
                  cdt.cdt_nome
          };

so i did this, but he is saying that these fields (win cdt inside of select new) do not exist in this context