# Getting last records of every distinct value of a column

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a message table like this:

```
Id     Message     Column1
--------------------------
1      asdasdd     1
2      dsfsfsf     1
3      safsafs     2
4      afewfff     3
5      adw qwd     2
```

I want to get last records of every distinct value on Column1, which means rows 2,4 and 5 via this code:

```
Messages.OrderByDescending(a => a.Id).GroupBy(a => a.Column1).Select(a => a.Key).ToList();
```

I only needs ids of rows, but nothing returns. I've done it with sql, but couldn't convert to EF lambda.

```
select max(Id) as Id from [Messages]
group by Column1
order by Id DESC
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/157786/how-do-i-get-the-max-row-with-a-group-by-in-linq-query so none of these worked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are selecting `key` which in `group by` means `column1` on which you are grouping the values. One way to get the values as you expected is to try something like below:

```
var query = Messages.GroupBy(item => item.Column1).Select(group =>   group.Last().Id)
        .OrderBy(item => item.Id)
        .Select(a => a.Id)
        .ToList();
```

*Or to get complete rows:*

```
var query = Messages.GroupBy(item => item.Column1)
        .Select(group => group.Last())
        .OrderBy(item => item.Id)
        .Select(a => a)
        .ToList();
```

Comment: i would say these would be slow in comparison to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/157786/how-do-i-get-the-max-row-with-a-group-by-in-linq-query