# Is there a better way to get full row of calculated group by using LINQ

Tags: c#, sql, linq, t-sql

This question is a further question to h[ttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/157786/how-do-i-get-the-max-row-with-a-group-by-in-linq-query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/157786/how-do-i-get-the-max-row-with-a-group-by-in-linq-query). Besides the max value and the group key, I need the every column of the row (including the most important one: ID).

For example, given students table

| ID | Name | Class | Score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | N0 | C0 | 0 |
| 2 | N1 | C0 | 1 |
| 3 | N2 | C1 | 1 |
| 4 | N3 | C1 | 2 |
| 5 | N4 | C1 | 3 |
| 6 | N5 | C2 | 4 |
| 7 | N6 | C2 | 5 |

To get full row of highest score student grouped by class, I figured out a way to do that, but not happy with the simplicity of it:

```cs
from o in Students
join o1 in
  (from oo in Students
   group oo by oo.Class
   into g
   select new { Class = g.Key, MaxScore = g.Max(x => x.Score)})
on o.Class + o.Score equals o1.Class + o1.MaxScore 
select o
```

My question is: is there simpler way to achieve above by using LINQ or raw MSSQL?

Comment: It always depends on the exact ORM (+ version) which LINQ query shapes are supported, so please add a tag for the ORM you're using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like selecting out of the grouping, which should use window functions

```cs
from o in Students
group o by o.Class into g
from s in g
where s.Score == g.Max(x => x.Score)
select s;
```

Another option, which does not give tied results

```cs
from o in Students
group o by o.Class into g
select g.OrderByDescending(x => x.Score).First();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also split it like:

1. Group students by their classes and find the maximum score for each class.
2. Join the original list of students with the maximum scores obtained in their respective classes.